# Could Sara have cheated death a second time?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, arrow

We see in the beginning of season 3 of Arrow that Sara dies (at the hands of a drugged Thea shooting arrows at Sara).

However, we also see later in the season that Roy "dies" fairly convincingly and is even legally/medically deemed dead. But we later find out that his "killer" was a specialist at faking realistic deaths, so it seems like no matter how realistic the death seems, it is possible for characters to live.

So that begs the question, could Merlyn have given Thea a drug that could allow her could "kill" Sara convincingly enough, but not actually kill her? Does there exist such a drug in the DC Television Universe?

Comment: Not sure if you've seen Season 4 yet, but they establish later that Sara was definitely killed by Thea. I can think of a few ways that she might have been made to survive, especially from other Arrowverse shows, but it's kind of moot since none were used. Are you looking for something that theoretically might have saved her?

Comment: Keep watching. You'll get your answer.

Comment: @AlfredoHernández I think the OP was asking for a way that Sara could fake her death. Yes, if they keep watching, they'll find that despite being dead dead, she still comes back to join the cast of *Legends of Tomorrow* (she's in the promotional material). But I don't think that's what they're looking for.

Comment: Not entirely sure what's being asked here.

Comment: I doubt it. Being overcome by supernatural bloodlust is unlikely to be sated by a coma-inducing poison or something like a shock to the heart.

Answer (score 1):

sara was killed but then brought back to life. no more has to be said